# variable used out of scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a responsive background video. I have this code.

```
<video id="bgvideo" />

function scaleVideo() {

    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    var videoNativeWidth = $('video#bgvideo')[0].videoWidth;
    var videoNativeHeight = $('video#bgvideo')[0].videoHeight;


    var heightScaleFactor = windowHeight / videoNativeHeight;
    var widthScaleFactor = windowWidth / videoNativeWidth;


    if (widthScaleFactor >= heightScaleFactor) {
        var scale = widthScaleFactor;
    } else {
        var scale = heightScaleFactor;
    }

    var scaledVideoHeight = videoNativeHeight * scale;
    var scaledVideoWidth  = videoNativeWidth * scale;

    $('video#bgvideo').height(scaledVideoHeight);
    $('video#bgvideo').width(scaledVideoWidth);
}
```

I'm using grunt to compile my code and etc.
Jshint of grunt is saying I'm using "scale" out of scope and I cant understand why.

Any suggests ?

[image: error]

Comment: I think JSHint's scope analysis doesn't consider blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function scaleVideo() {
    var scale; //this is the change

    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    var videoNativeWidth = $('video#bgvideo')[0].videoWidth;
    var videoNativeHeight = $('video#bgvideo')[0].videoHeight;


    var heightScaleFactor = windowHeight / videoNativeHeight;
    var widthScaleFactor = windowWidth / videoNativeWidth;


    if (widthScaleFactor >= heightScaleFactor) {
        scale = widthScaleFactor; //simply modify the value here
    } else {
        scale = heightScaleFactor;
    }

    var scaledVideoHeight = videoNativeHeight * scale;
    var scaledVideoWidth  = videoNativeWidth * scale;

    $('video#bgvideo').height(scaledVideoHeight);
    $('video#bgvideo').width(scaledVideoWidth);
}
```

Comment: *"The var scale is defined only in the `if..else..` scope."* `if/else` statements don't create scope though.

Answer (score 6):

You should not write `var scale = heightScaleFactor;` inside the `else` statement  if you want to use it outside of it.

Initialize `scale` outside the `if`

```
 var scale;
 if (widthScaleFactor >= heightScaleFactor) {
     scale = widthScaleFactor;
 } else {
     scale = heightScaleFactor;
 }
```

Comment: *"You cannot write `var scale = heightScaleFactor;` inside of else loop."* Sure you can.