# The function in ajax when parse to it number like 1 or 2 work but when I parse with varible not work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have function in ajax. When  I send  a number with a  function it works but when I send it with a variable it does not work.

```
function display_message(userID) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "displaychat.php",
    method: "post",
    data: {
      touid: userID
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('.msg_push' + userID).html('');
      //$('.msg-right').html('');
      // $('.msg-left').html('').hide(); `enter code here`
      $('.msg_push' + userID).append(data);

      var objDiv = $('.msg_body');

      if (objDiv.length > 0) {
        var height = objDiv[0].scrollHeight;
        objDiv.scrollTop(height);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: "Not work" , what doesnt work? Do you get an error? And whats in this variable you're passing.

Comment: when i call  display_message(userID) not work and when i call  display_message(19) it is work

Comment: What is in the variable userID ? What is the error you get?

Comment: var userID = $(this).attr("class");

Comment: attr class//
<tr  id="sidebar-user-box" class="'.$fetchUserCm['u_id'].' "  ruid="'.$id.' " >

Comment: In chat box when i parse 19 the content of messages appear  in chat box but when i parse userID to the function  not appear anything appear  in chat box

Answer (score 0):

..since I can't comment.....

If by "not work" it sends a null value, then probably any of the following

- `userId` is not defined...(maybe you made a typo by declaring `userid` or `UserId` rather than `userId
- `userId` was [used out of scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103808/variable-used-out-of-scope)

  **-  Since you are using php, maybe userId was not initialised or given a null value when the page loads (maybe the user was not logged
  in**

Comment: in the same code  '<div class="msg_head">'+userID+ i see the value of userID

Comment: change $(this).attr("class"); to $('.msg_head).html();

Comment: i write  '<div class="msg_head">'+userID+ to see  userID have vale or null